# How to map chucked json data in Restkit 0.24 iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, restkit

This the error i get on a GET request which has chucked data:

```
2015-06-05 18:18:30.293 DOTB[1557:561012] E restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:355 Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'
```

This issue here is that restkit starts mapping data before  all the chucks arrive.

When the Api end-point is called from a rest-client then the data is ok it's format is correct.
The restkit version i m using is 0.24 an it is configured correctly, all other request made to the same end-point returns desired results, and if i reduce the quantity of the records to 15 its starts working but it fails when the api returns 20 records.

1: How to handle response which is in large quantity without using Pagination?

Any other solutions would be appreciated.

Here is the section from which the error is fired from:

```
- (id)parseResponseData:(NSError **)error
    {
        NSString *MIMEType = [self.response MIMEType];
        __block NSError *underlyingError = nil;
        __block id object;
        dispatch_sync(RKResponseMapperSerializationQueue(), ^{
            object = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:self.data MIMEType:MIMEType error:&underlyingError];
        });    
        if (! object) {
            NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [userInfo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loaded an unprocessable response (%ld) with content type '%@'", (long) self.response.statusCode, MIMEType]
                        forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            [userInfo setValue:[self.response URL] forKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey];
            [userInfo setValue:underlyingError forKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
            NSError *HTTPError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:RKErrorDomain code:NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse userInfo:userInfo];

            if (error) *error = HTTPError;

            return nil;
        }
        return object;
    }
```

Comment: Are the headers on the response correct? On iOS you should probably use pagination rather than big downloads...

Comment: @Wain the headers are correct, the issue is that restkit starts mapping data chucks before all the chucks have arrived.

Comment: But you look to control the download so it's that you pass the data to RestKit too soon

Comment: The download is controlled by restkit, an when i request the api this is the response i get: 'E restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:355 Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json''